# Usb sound card and mic not working

Tags: usb, audio

I have connected a usb sound card to my rpi 3 model B but the problem is even though the speaker connected through the sound card is working the mic is not. If I try

```
arecord -d 10 -D hw:0,0 -r 16000 -f S16_LE -c1 /home/pi/mic-test.wav
```

OR

```
arecord --device=hw:0,0 --format S16_LE --rate 44100 -c1 test.wav
```

I get only noise which is there even if I remove the mic from the sound card

I have made the USB audio card index = 0 
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get recording to work from my USB headset, which may be approximately the same... as long as the default sound card drivers work... I needed to select device 1 as follows:

```
arecord -d 10 -D hw:1,0 -r 16000 -f S16_LE -c1 /home/pi/mic-test.wav
```

Rather than device 0, which should be the Raspberry Pi audio.

I also needed to unmute the microphone in `alsamixer`  Make sure you select the USB device via the <kbd>F6</kbd> menu... then <kbd>F5</kbd> for all channels.

Comment: Yes but I changed the order to: 0: USB audio and 1: Pi Audio